# I can't quote swift viewController class into Objective-c projects

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a Objective-c project at present.I need to add swift programming language in the Objective-c project.I imported prjectName-Swift.h,but I created swift file in Objective-c project,I can't quote swift file in Objective-c project.Below is I set the example, I use the pictures to present.I use the Xcode version is 8.3.3[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAqT9.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzeTe.jpg)

Comment: for that you need to create Bridging Header File

Comment: @ Nishant Bhindi  I don't create Bridging Header File.Because，when I refer to information, quote swift file in Objective-c project does not  create Bridging Header File.just quote Objective-c file in Swift project need create Bridging Header File. Is that right?

Comment: @Nishant Bhindi， Thank you so much. I tried your suggestion,has solved the problem.